# Automating Firefox and Chrome browsers

Tags: firefox, testing, automation, google-chrome

I am looking for a way to automate a couple of browsers like Firefox and Chrome (for now on just on Windows) from an external application/process.

Is there a way to do things along these lines:

1. Start the browser with a URL
2. Have the browser load the page, run scripts etc.
3. Inspect the DOM

For reference, IE can be automated using the `InternetExplorer.Application` object which can be created in a shell script using the following JavasSript. I can then walk the DOM API:

```
var ie = new ActiveXObject('InternetExplorer.Application');
```

The motivating scenario here is automated testing. I'd like to load the page containing the test code and gather results after the test has run.

Comment: Look at the Watin library, it supports Firefox and has experimental support for Chrome (as well as IE) http://watin.sourceforge.net/

Comment: If you're familiar with Ruby, use [Watir](http://watir.com/). If you're familiar with .NET, use [Watin](http://watin.sourceforge.net/). Also consider [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/). It has a Firefox plug-in for recording your tests, and it also has a mechanism for running tests in multiple browsers or platforms.

Comment: Try Puppeteer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17994483/automating-firefox-or-google-chrome/77612650#77612650

Answer (score 11, accepted):

https://sourceforge.net/projects/watin/

WatiN does exactly that, and I believe they recently added Chrome support.

Update 6/22/2011:

Currrently WatiN only works on Firefox 2 and 3, not in Firefox 4 (and almost certainly not in Firefox 5, which was released today).  Also, at the time of this answer, Chrome support was supposedly being added, but it looks like that never got fully baked and now is not listed as a supported platform on their home page.

Also worth noting, in my experience WatiN got a lot slower when I upgraded to IE9.  I saw this on two different machines, and downgrading to IE8 sped the tests back up on both machines.

I still use WatiN heavily, but now mostly for behavior driven design and functional regression testing, which generally are not browser-specific.  Then, manually test in FF and Chrome for all regression testing.

Update 9/22/2015:

Elmue is right, it looks like WatiN is no longer being worked on.  We're looking into Selenium for our automated acceptance tests now: https://www.selenium.dev/

Comment: It seems that the Watin project is dead. The last update on Sourceforge was 2011.

Comment: Yeah, it's a shame.  WatiN was a great piece of software and looks like it died off a few years ago.

Answer (score 0):

TestR will let you automated IE, FF, and Chrome. I've started working on Edge support but just haven't had the time.

https://github.com/BobbyCannon/TestR

You can use the nuget package.

https://www.nuget.org/packages/TestR/

Here is some examples.

https://docs.epiccoders.com/Page/35/TestR