# Create a Chrome instance in WatiN

Tags: c#, google-chrome, watin

I have been using WatiN with IE with great success, however am now wanting to move onto Chrome. It seems to me that if I can just create an instance of a Chrome browser it should be a similar process, but creating an instance of Chrome is proving to be a tricky task.
I am currently looking at:
WatiN.Core.Native.Chrome.ChromeBrowser
Am I on the right track? Or am I missing assemblies for a WatiN.Core.Chrome?

EDIT:
I have now investigated Selenium and am using it with some success for Chrome, Firefox and IE. For those requiring multiple browser support I would suggest Selenium over WatiN, at least till they have finalised their Firefox and Chrome implementations. Both are very handy for UI testing in general though!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Official [website](http://watin.org/) states that only supported browsers are IE 6-9 and FF 2-3. Chrome browser is only in experimental mode and isn't yet supported. There are couple of so [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2320516/automating-firefox-and-chrome-browsers) stating that there was no success using chrome in Watin.

Comment: I had originally thought 'experimental' meant that it is there but not fully functional. Firefox appears to be working well, so I will be glad for what I already have :) and thank you for confirming this for me.